# Scope inside constructor

Tags: javascript

I have an instance of a constructor called SlideShow and I wanted to know what the scope of a variable with the key word var would be.
I understand this refers to the object itself but not sure what scope the itemWidth would be. I presume its local to the function but if the function is global does this mean the var inside it is too? can var itemWidth be accessed from anywhere else?

```
function SlideShow( width, height ){
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  var itemWidth = 400;  
}
```

I presume the var inside the update method with is part of the objects prototype object would be local to that function and not global.

```
SlideShow.prototype.update = function( dir ){
        var dir = value;
}
```

Comment: Should be easy to test isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`function` defines scope. Anything declared inside a function with `var` is local, and visible only inside that function (or functions declared inside it). In both of your examples, the var in question is only visible inside the function.

Comment: Not just functions declared inside it, but also all functions created by function expressions inside it.

Comment: Indeed, anything created in that scope.